# c++ return string or char from user input

Tags: c++, string, qt, return-value, cin

im trying to return a string/char (tried with both) from a funtion:

```
 char* foo(void)

    {

    using namespace std;
   // char Name[100];
    std::string Name;
    std::cout << "Type your name : ";
    //std::getline(std::cin, Name);
    std::cin >> Name;

    // std::cout << "Hello " << Name << "\n";

   // std::string str(Name);
    return Name;
    }
```

which gives me this error:

> /home/peter/netsend/main.cpp:22: error: cannot convert
>   'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}' to
>   'char*' in return
>        return Name;
>               ^

If i use char Name[100];
i get this warning when i compile my program:

> /home/petter/netsend/main.cpp:13: warning: address of local variable
>   'Name' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
>        char Name[100];
>             ^

when i run it i get:

> ype your name : hh terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'std::logic_error'   what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not
>   valid Aborted (core dumped)

if i run this directly in int main it works:

```
using namespace std;
   // char Name[100];
    std::string Name;
    std::cout << "Type your name : ";
    //std::getline(std::cin, Name);
    std::cin >> Name;

    // std::cout << "Hello " << Name << "\n";

   // std::string str(Name);
```

then i could use Name in my other functions in int main.
any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try `return Name.c_str()`

Comment: Because a string != char array. In the first one, you say you're returning a char-pointer, but you instead try to return a String. Change the return type to string. And don't use uppercase names for variables. Uppercase is for types.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, If that ignored the `const` difference and compiled, it would return a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, That's up to the coding style. LLVM uses uppercase (upper camel case) variable names. The standard uses lowercase (snake case) type names.

Comment: @chris I've never heard of uppercase names being preferred anywhere. OK, we'll then ignore my comment if that's the case here.

Comment: @chris I agree. Should copy `Name.c_str()` to new char array and return it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return a `string`, like this:

```
auto foo()
    -> std::string
{
    using namespace std;
    string Name;
    cout << "Type your name : ";
    getline( cin, Name );
    return Name;
}
```

Or instead of the C++11 "trailing return type" syntax, use the old syntax

```
std::string foo()
```

… which means the same and is still much more common, but can't be used in every case.

Answer (score 0):

I will divide your problem into cases which I will describe briefly.

1. If you create a local array, namely `char Name[100]` and return it, you will end up with a `dangling pointer`. `Name[100]` is an `automatic` variable which means that once the function goes out of scope the `pointer` that is returned by the function will point to an invalid memory location.
2. `return Name` when `Name` is an `std::string`. Well, here you have a type mismatch. Your function returns a `char*` and you return a `std::string`. Hence, your compiler issues an error.

To fix your issue declare `Name` as a `std::string` and declare the function to return a `std::string` like this:  `std::string foo(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you should probably return a `string` (i.e., `std::string foo(void) { ... }`) and then simply use `string::c_str()` to get the C-style string from it when/if needed.

In the second case, the compiler is exactly right. You cannot safely use a variable after its scope has ended, that will be undefined behaviour. The `char` array ceases to exist when the function exits and you're returning the pointer to its first character, a big no=-no.